# How to include JavaScript in Shopify's checkout pages

Tags: javascript, shopify, checkout

Does anyone know if it is possible to add or include JavaScript to any of the 3 tabs on the Shopify checkout pages -- Customer information, Shipping method, or Payment method?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shopify Plus plan allows for customisations on the Checkout page. ( 
but the price is $1000+ a month )

Other than that you can add only javascript to the last step which is the one after the payment.